# Что такое Tomcat, Jboss и др.?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, tomcat, jboss

Опыт веб программирования: неделя. Да, я знаю, что это сервера приложений, но насколько я понял (почти уверен, что не прав) это только эмуляторы серверов.

Как мне кинуть приложение на реальный сервер?

Можно ли это сделать с помощью `Tomcat`'а или `Jboss`'а?

Используют ли их крупные компании, и если да, то для каких целей?

Comment: см [Web Server vs Application Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcmUOmvl1N8).

Comment: Это и есть сервера на которых можно крутить свои проекты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat и JBoss это сервера приложений написанные на Java и позволяющие запускать Java вэб приложения. Это реальные сервера, работающие по основному протоколу HTTP или HTTPS и принимающие запросы клиентских приложений, таких как браузер или curl.

Это реальные сервера и вы можете устанавливать на них приложения, которые *могут* на них работать. Это важно знать какие требования у приложения, прежде чем устанавливать его на соответствующий сервер.

Компании часто используют эти сервера в своей инфраструктуре, а также создают архитектурные решения с помощью этих серверов и технологий обеспечиваемых ими.